# SSRS Sub-Report Won't Load Until Refresh

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS 2008 report with a sub-report that takes a selected value as a parameter. For example, I have a report that takes in `@ProjectID` and then selects `ClientID`. If I pass `[ClientID]` as a parameter to the sub report I get an error the first time I load the report. However, subsequent loads (clicking refresh) all work fine. I do not have this problem if I pass the parameter directly to the sub-report, ie `[@ProjectID]`.

Is SSRS passing along parameters before the select is issued so it's only working when it caches the values upon refreshing? Is there any way I can fix this without forcing all sub-reports to take in `[@ProjectID]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. It did indeed appear to be an error with trying to populate the parameters before the query was run. I solved this by placing the sub-reports in a table which appears to delay rendering until the query has completed.

Comment: Thank you... this saved me 5 years later. I have a subreport with no dataset for formating purpose and it seems as if it rendered too fast. Adding a dataset with a simple dummy query "select 'dummy' as dummy" in my subreport did the trick.